# Can't import package from parallel directory

Tags: python

I have 3 folders in my project: `scripts` , `src`, `tests`. In `scripts`, I have a script to populate my local db with test data (`populate_db.py`). In the `tests` folder, I have a file called `generators.py`, which I'm trying to import into `populate_db.py` , but I'm not having any luck. I have this:

```
code_path = Path("../")
sys.path.append(code_path / "tests")
from generators import UserFactory
```

but I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'generators'`. Strange thing, is I do

```
sys.path.append(code_path / "src")
from users.models import User
```

and that imports fine. Not sure what I've done differently/wrong. I also tried a relative import: `from ..generators import UserFactory`, but got `attempted relative import with no known parent package`. I do have `__init__.py` in the parent and tests directories (though there are no python files in the parent, only in the 3 children).

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be as `sys.path.append(code_path+"tests")`?

Comment: Interestingly, no. Seems like `pathlib.Path` divides to append string? It's weird, I know, but if I do `code_path.cwd()`, it shows the correct path, heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the correct way to add a path to `sys.path` when using the `pathlib.Path` is to convert it to a string:

```
sys.path.append(str(code_path / "tests"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from .tests.generators import UserFactory
```

Comment: Nah, I just get `attempted relative import with no known parent package`